# How to horizontally concatenate dataframes with duplicated indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge 2 dataframes to give this result:

[image]

How can this be achieved in Pandas?

Comment: Please provide your two inputs in a reproducible format, ideally as code for a DataFrame constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "index" the index, you need to deduplicate the index with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([
  df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True),
  df2.set_index(df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
], axis=1).droplevel(-1)
```

Output:

```
  var1 var2 var1 var2
1    a    b    k    l
2    c    d    m    n
2    e    f  NaN  NaN
3    g    h    o    p
3    i    j    q    r
4  NaN  NaN    s    t
```

Reproducible inputs:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list('abcdefghij')).reshape(-1,2),
                   columns=['var1', 'var2'], index=[1,2,2,3,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list('klmnopqrst')).reshape(-1,2),
                   columns=['var1', 'var2'], index=[1,2,3,3,4])
```